# SMS Gateway - BASH Script - ZABBIX

Tags: bash, shell, zabbix, sms-gateway

I have a sms gateway to sending alerts from zabbix calling by bash script. 
To send sms i use http request like:

```
http://SERVERIP/EasyAdmin/SmsSender?login=LOGIN&password=PASSWORD&remote_id=ID&class0=0&phone=${1}&text=${2}
```

login, password, id and class are const

i have 2 variable forwarded by zabbix - phone and text

simple script:

```
PHONE=$1
SUBJECT=$2

curl -i -H "Accept: application/xml" -X GET "http://10.151.92.151:9080/EasyAdmin/SmsSender?login=cortex_acs&password=cortex_acs&remote_id=2422&class0=0&phone=${PHONE}&text=${SUBJECT}"
exit 0
```

if i execute script in cmd like ./sms.sh phonenr tekst
everything is okay, but when zabbix need to execute this script, variable are null

Comment: I'm not familiar with zabbix but if it makes sense you should include the way you're calling the script from zabbix.

Comment: Zabbix just call script with input parameters $1, $2 and $3 - are bound to the address of the recipient, the subject and the text of the message, respectively. In this curl is everything ok ?

Comment: Yeah the script seems alright. I would remove the `exit 0` though, it makes the script exit status meaningless ; without it the script will return the exit status of the curl command, which you can chose to ignore

Comment: Okay i have a step forward, now zabbix send sms but empty... when trigger is up i have a sms message but empty, without any data.

Comment: I don't see where you supposedly map this third "text of the message" parameter? From the script you posted it looks like it's ignored, nothing refers to the 3rd positional parameter.

Comment: i ignore third parameter in script and also in zabbix, so i dont think this is a clue of problem

Comment: Which version of Zabbix? Show a screenshot of media type configuration from Zabbix.

Answer (score 0):

Are you set the script's parameter Respectively (in zabbix frontend)

like the zabbix documentation:

```
https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manual/config/notifications/media/script
```

make sure about script permissions (for zabbix user) and go to debug mode for have more information on log file